# scrbook: Roman page numbers in TOC are wider than textwidth?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, align, scrbook

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}%
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}

\pagenumbering{arabic}%

\chapter{Arabic Chapter}
\chapter{Arabic Chapter}
\chapter{Arabic Chapter}

\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, the `Roman` letters are wider than the `\textwidth` what looks really ugly. How can I `right align` the `Roman numbers` below each other in one row?

---

**Update:** While playing around with `\documentclass{book}`, suddenly the `TOC` does appear like expected. Now I am curious - what could be the issue in `scrbook`?

Comment: If you add sections to the part with Roman page numbers you will get the same issue with standard classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the default the pagenumbers are right aligned in box of `\@pnumwidth` (default is 1.55em). This box is to small for the Roman numbers.

Assuming there are only chapters with Roman page numbers:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocpagenumberbox=\mbox
]{chapter}
```

or

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocpagenumberbox={\makebox[3em][r]}% adjust the width to your needs
]{chapter}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocpagenumberbox=\mbox
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}
%\section{Roman Section}
\chapter{Roman Chapter}

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\chapter{Arabic Chapter}
\chapter{Arabic Chapter}
\chapter{Arabic Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

If there are also sections etc. with Roman pagenumbers, then you could change `\@pnumwidth` (works for standard classes too):

```latex
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{3em}
\makeatother
```

or you could use `\RedeclareSectionCommands`:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocpagenumberbox={\makebox[3em][r]}% adjust the width to your needs
]{chapter,section,subsection}
```

---

The next KOMA-Script version 3.27 will provide an option `pagenumberwidth` for the TOC entry style `tocline`. With prefix `toc` (`topagenumberwidth`) this option can be used in `\RedeclareSectionCommand` or `\RedeclareSectionCommands`.

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocpagenumberwidth=3em% needs at least version 3.27.3161
]{chapter,section,subsection}
```

If you want to test this new option you can install the [prerelease from the KOMA-Script website](https://komascript.de/node/1801).